# Arnold on proof of uniqueness

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-explanation

In his proof of Uniqueness, Arnold mentions the integral approaches infinity as `x3` approaches `x2`. How does he come about this conclusion?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming we know that $x_1 \lt x_3 \lt x_2$, then

$$\int_{x_1}^{x_3} \frac{d \xi}{k(\xi - x_2)}= \frac 1k \ln \frac{x_3-x_2}{x_1-x_2}.$$

If $x_3 \to x_2$, then the argument of the logarithm approaches $0$.

Comment: That's true when he states it for the second time but the first time he states it, the function is not known. It's stated for the first time right below the first equation.

Comment: The point is that $\vert t_3-t_1 \vert $ is equal to the integral you care about and he's shown that it's greater than an integral that you can easily calculate tends to infinity.

Comment: Ah, so he's constructing this integral to prove the prior statement.